# Автозаполнение классов в Atom Editor

Tags: atom

Недавно перешел на этот редактор. Пока нравится своей быстротой. Есть много дополнений. Но вот чего не хватает - это автозаполнение классов. Что я имею ввиду. Например, у меня есть класс User. И когда где то в коде я хочу создать экземпляр этого класса

```
$tmp=new User();
```

я хочу что бы оно находило этот класс и показывало его методы. То есть, как делает phpstorm. Может есть какое то разширение для этого?